# Error file_get_contents with twitter search api

Tags: json, search, curl, twitter, file-get-contents

I have the following problem: when this script runs

```
    $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=obama';
    $tw = file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);
```

I receive this message.

```
Warning (2): file_get_contents(http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=obama) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 420 Client Error (420)
```

But it's very strange because it has always been working!
Can you help me?
Adding...I tried to use CURL in this way

```
$url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=obama';
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$contents = curl_exec($c);
echo $contents;
curl_close($c);
```

but call returned this message
"error":"You have been rate limited. Enhance your calm."} and it seemed absurd because I didn't make any request before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found everywhere that the best practice in this case is use CURL.
I don't know why but then I tried to pass parameter ('obama') with *urlencode* and it seems to be that syntax (previously incorrect) the main cause of this warning.